# activate conditionalPanel if file exists

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I ask for input from user and based on the input determine if a file exists in my database ("/data"). If the file exists, I would like to activate a conditionalPanel with widgets for display and download.

I tried using reactive but it doesn't seem to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
      radioButtons(
      inputId = "method",
      label = "what method?",
      choices = list(
        "mixcr" = 'mixcr',
        "phlat" = 'phlat'
      ),
      selected = 'mixcr'
    ),
                 textInput("input_type","Enter the ID"),
                 actionButton("submit","Submit"),    
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "!is.null(output.factorflag)",
                 actionButton('load_csv', 'Load csv'),
                 downloadButton("down", label = "Download the data.")),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput('dt'))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    if (input$submit) 
    {
    if (input$method == 'mixcr') {
      infile <- paste0('data/mixcr/', input$input_type, '.clones.tsv')
    } else if (input$method == 'phlat') {
      infile <- paste0('data/phlat/', input$input_type, '_HLA.sum')
    }
    if (!file.exists(isolate({infile}))) {return(NULL)}
  }})
  output$factorflag <- reactive({return(!is.null(df()))})
  outputOptions(output, "factorflag", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `renderUI` to perform server side processing.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "method",
    label = "what method?",
    choices = list(
      "mixcr" = 'mixcr',
      "phlat" = 'phlat'
    ),
    selected = 'mixcr'
  ),
  textInput("input_type","Enter the ID"),
  actionButton("submit","Submit"),  
  uiOutput("loadme"),
  # conditionalPanel(
  #   condition = "!is.null(output.factorflag)",
  #   actionButton('load_csv', 'Load csv'),
  #   downloadButton("down", label = "Download the data.")),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput('dt'))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    if (input$submit) 
    {
      if (input$method == 'mixcr') {
        infile <- paste0('data/mixcr/', input$input_type, '.clones.tsv')
      } else if (input$method == 'phlat') {
        infile <- paste0('data/phlat/', input$input_type, '_HLA.sum')
      }
      if (!file.exists(isolate({infile}))) {return(NULL)}
    }})
  output$loadme <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(df())) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      actionButton('load_csv', 'Load csv'),
      downloadButton("down", label = "Download the data.")
    )
  })
  output$factorflag <- reactive({return(!is.null(df()))})
  outputOptions(output, "factorflag", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks! It seems though that the test `is.null(df())` always returns true so the conditional widgets never appear.

Comment: I added `else {return(infile)}` and now it works :)